# Virtual File or 'link' file

Tags: file, hyperlink, hook, virtual

I need to create a "virtual file", a file that if some program access that file, e can answer the size, permissions, and 'say' what is writen in it.

Why?
I have a Virtual Machine that have and Virtual Hard Disk, and i need that file be a 'link' to other and far location (unknow by Virtual Machine Program)
When the VM try to read, i need to 'say' what is writen, and when it´s try to write, i need to store in other location.
In most cases the file is in a network and splited in many computers (like a Network FileSystem) then i need to know every change/access/read in file and deal with the request.
I can't modify/inject the target program (third-party).

I found a question in this site about Virtual File, but i need to know in real time all changes in the file.
I searched for File Hooks and found nothing.
I tryed to use a virtual driver, but it´s hard to find some code (like Daemon Tools, but with Read/Write).
I thought in a remote folder (or mapped drive) with FTP, but the file size is TOO big (10-50 GB) and i need to read specific sections of the file.

Thanks in advance for any help.
(Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968).

Comment: Muito obrigado, estou tentando com o Dokan.